# Really strange JS error in Underscore.js file when rendering view

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have 2 views right now. One lists a collection of mongoDb objects, and the other is supposed to allow editing the er. The list view works completely fine, but whenever I try to render the edit view, I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

And here is the code it failed on (line 1155 of Underscore.js):

```
try {
      render = new Function(settings.variable || 'obj', '_', source);
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    } catch (e) {
      e.source = source;
      throw e;
    }
```

And here is my code that causes the above code to run:

```
render : function(){

                        var id = glob;

                        var skill = new SkillModel({_id:id});
                        skill.fetch();

                        console.log("BLAH");
                        var template = _.template($('#editTemplate').html(), {skill: {name:"Test", value:"Value", id:"123"}});

                        this.$el.html(template);

                        return this;
                    }
```

I have found that the line:

```
var template = _.template($('#editSkillTemplate').html(), {});
```

is the line that causes it to happen. The strange thing is that I have done everything just like my listView render function, so I have no idea what the problem is. Just in case it is useful, here is my code for the list view.

```
render : function(){
                var that = this;

                var skillset = new SkillSet();
                skillset.fetch({success: function(model, result){

                var template = _.template($('#skillsTemplate').html(), {items: result });

                that.$el.html(template);

                }}) 

                return this;            

            }
```

Here is the template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="editTemplate">
                <section>
                    <form id="editForm">
                        <label for="skillName"><input id="skillName" type="text" value="<%= skill.name %>" />
                        <br />
                        <label for="skillValue"><input id="skillValue" type="text" value="<%= skill.value $>" />
                        <br />
                        <a href="#/save/<%= skill.id %>"><button class="save">Save</button></a>
                        <a href="#/delete/<%= skill.id %>"><button class="delete">Delete</button></a>
                    </form>
                </section>
            </script>
```

Comment: Since this seems to be coming from the `Function` constructor, it would be more interesting to see the `source` (or `e.source` of the thrown Error)

Comment: You need to post the template syntax that is within the HTML #skillsTemplate tag. That's where the syntax error is, not in your javascript.

Comment: Oh really?? Ok I will post it

Comment: @PeterLyons Ok I updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple typo:

```
<%= skill.value $>
```

should be

```
<%= skill.value %>
```

Comment: omg haha thank you so much. Idk how I didn't see that at all. Helps to have 2 pairs of eyes. Thank you

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know much about using Backbone with  Nodejs and MongoDb back end would you? I am having trouble doing a model.fetch({_id:myid}). I think it is because technically the mongodb needs a BSON object, not just a string

Comment: Yes, I know those frameworks. Post another question. Mongo's use of BSON is entirely transparent (an implementation detail). You send it JavaScript objects and you don't have to worry at all about BSON. However, for querying by ID you will need a real ObjectId("longIDStringhere") instance and not a string.